# Can anyone give some hints on how to solve this differencial equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$
\left( 2ye^{y/x} + x \right) \frac{dy}{dx} - 2x - y = 0.
$$

I have a really hard time thinking how to separate x and y variables

Comment: sorry but this is my first time posting, click on 'enter image description here' in order to see question

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I tried to convert to polar coordinates, not more amenable either. $ \log (1+\frac12 \tan \theta)= \frac{\tan \theta+ r/r'}{1- \tan \theta ~r/ r'}$

Answer (score 2):

Since you're only asking for a hint, I suggest letting $y=ux$, $dy/dx=u+(x)(du/dx)$. Then your equation becomes
$$
(2uxe^u+x)(u+x\,du/dx)-2x-ux=0
$$
and you may be able to take it from there.

Answer (score 1):

This is a  first order differential form, that is not the differential of a differentiable function
$$(2\ y\ e^{y/x}\ +\ x)\ dy  =   (2\ x + \ y)\  dx $$
So one has to find an integrating factor

$$  f(x,y)\  (2\ y\ e^{y/x}\ +\ x)\ dy  =  f(x,y) \ (2\ x + \ y) \ dx $$

such that

$$ d(f(x,y)\  (2\ y\ e^{y/x}\ +\ x)\ dy - f(x,y) \ (2\ x + \ y) \ dx)  =0 $$
Often one finds a separable integrating factor $f(x,y) = g(x)\ h(x)$, one factor possibly a constant, because this is the most frequent ansatz in exercises, that come from rather simple functions, differentiated and taking the common numerator. Seems not to be an easy task here.

The other path is to find a transformation of coordinates, eg
$$ {x = v/u, y = u v, dx = dv/u - v du/u^2, dy = u dv + v du}$$
or something like that, such that the differential form becomes tranparent geometrically.

Answer (score 0):

Let implicit function $F(c,x,y)=-(c-2 \log (x))+2 \tanh ^{-1}\left(1-\frac{2 y^2 e^{y/x}}{x^2}\right)+2 \log \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)=0$.

Use implicit differentiation:

$$\frac{\partial F(c,x,y(x))}{\partial x}=\frac{x \left(-y'(x)\right)-2 e^{\frac{y(x)}{x}} y(x) y'(x)+y(x)+2 x}{x^2-e^{\frac{y(x)}{x}} y(x)^2}=0$$

$$\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2 x+y}{2 y e^{y/x}+x}$$

Substitute $\frac{dy}{dx}$ into ODE:

$$\frac{\left(2 y e^{y/x}+x\right) (2 x+y)}{2 y e^{y/x}+x}-2 x-y=0$$

Hence, ODE is satisfied with implicit $F(c,x,y)=0$.

**Addendum** How to get function F?

Transforming the ODE with $u=\frac{y}{x}$ we get:

$$u'(x)\to -\frac{2 \left(e^{u(x)} u(x)^2-1\right)}{x \left(2 e^{u(x)} u(x)+1\right)}$$

$$\int \frac{2 e^u u+1}{e^u u^2-1} \, du=c+\int -\frac{2}{x} \, dx$$

$$2 \tanh ^{-1}\left(1-2 e^u u^2\right)+2 \log (u)=c-2 \log (x)$$

Then substitute $u=\frac{y}{x}$, subtract RHS and you've got $F(c,x,y)$.

Comment: yea also confused about how F came about

Comment: OP asked for *hints*, gpmath.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, Other comments asked for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start where Gerry Myerson stopped. Simplifying
$$
(2uxe^u+x)(u+x\,du/dx)-2x-ux=0, \tag{1}
$$
we obtain
$$
(2ue^u+1)x\frac{du}{dx}=2-2u^2e^u \implies \int\frac{2ue^u+1}{u^2e^u-1}du=
-2\int\frac{dx}{x}=-2\ln x + C. \tag{2}
$$
Now, let $v=u^2e^u-1$; then
$$
\frac{dv}{du}=(u^2+2u)e^{u}=(u^2e^{u}-1)+(2ue^{u}+1) 
$$
$$
\implies \frac{dv}{u^2e^{u}-1}=\frac{dv}{v}=\left(1+\frac{2ue^{u}+1}{u^2e^{u}-1}\right)du, \tag{3}
$$
hence
$$
\int\frac{2ue^u+1}{u^2e^u-1}du = \int\frac{dv}{v}-\int du = 
\ln v - u = \ln(u^2e^{u}-1)-u. \tag{4}
$$
Substituting $(4)$ in $(2)$, and recalling that $u=\frac{y}{x}$, we finally obtain the solution to the original ODE in implicit form:
$$
\ln\left(\frac{y^2}{x^2}e^{y/x}-1\right)-\frac{y}{x}+2\ln x = C
$$
$$
\implies y^2-x^2e^{-y/x}=C'. \tag{5}
$$

Comment: OP asked for *hints*.